# OpsCenter 5.1.2 fails to start with SSL enabled on CentOS 5

Tags: python, cassandra, opscenter, datastax-enterprise

This applies to OpsCenter 5.1.0 and 5.1.1 as well.

I got the following error when trying to run OpsCenter 5.1.2 on a CentOS 5 server:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 317, in startApplication
app.startApplication(application, not self.config['no_save'])
File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/application/app.py", line 653, in startApplication
service.IService(application).startService()
File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/application/service.py", line 277, in startService
service.startService()
File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1141, in unwindGenerator
return _inlineCallbacks(None, f(*args, **kwargs), Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/OpsCenterdService.py", line 45, in startService
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/OpsCenterdService.py", line 101, in setupWebServer
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 120, in makeWebServer
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/SslUtils.py", line 2, in <module>
exceptions.ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
```

python26 is installed from EPEL.  This is OpsCenter from Datastax.  SSL support worked fine with OpsCenter 5.0.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyOpenSSL is not included with python26 from EPEL.  It has to be installed manually.  Fortunately this can be done easily with the easy_install python module (included with setuptools), but that will need to be installed manually first.

Install the required packages for building pyOpenSSL and setuptools:

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ libffi-devel openssl-devel
```

Download and install setuptools:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget --no-check-certificate https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-16.0.tar.gz
tar zxf setuptools-16.0.tar.gz
cd setuptools-16.0
python26 setup.py install
```

<sup>Note: it would be good to check if a newever version of setuptools is available.</sup>

Install pyOpenSSL:

```
python26 -m easy_install pyOpenSSL
```

Ensure you are using the `python26` command not just `python`, since CentOS 5 has Python 2.4 installed.

SSL support for OpsCenter should work now.